# Assignment of pointers?

Tags: c, pointers

```
int arr[]={1,2,3};
char* p;
p=arr;
```

This is a fragment of a program and it works.

Can anyone explain how can an int variable address be assigned to char pointer?

Comment: did you check p[1]? It should not be '2'

Comment: printf("%d", *p); prints 2

Comment: p = (int*)(p+1); this prints *p as 0.

Comment: @user3465845: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @user3465845: While the behavior is platform-dependent, `printf("%d", *p)` cannot realistically print `2` in any case. You are making something up.

Comment: Turn up your warning level on your compiler, and heed any warnings given. End of question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, because size of char pointer is the same as size of an int pointer. However, when some pointer arithmetic will be applied, you won't get valid results. It means that if you would like to access second element of your array - `p[1]` then only one byte would added to the p address. If `p` would be of type int, then 4 byte would be added (since that's the size of int) and second element would be accessed properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3};
    char* p;
    p = arr;
    printf("%d\n", p[0]);
    printf("%d\n", p[1]);

    int* pp = arr;
    printf("%d\n", pp[0]);
    printf("%d\n", pp[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
1
0  - as you can see that is not the value from arr[1]
1
2
```

As I have intel processor, which is in little endian, `arr[0]` in memory is stored as following:

```
01 00 00 00
^
p[0]
```

`p[1]` which is equivalent to *(p + 1), will add one byte to p pointer, because size of p is char.

```
01 00 00 00
   ^
   p[1]
```

and `printf("%d\n, p[1]);` gives 0. Note that if you were on big endian machine, the result of printing `p[0]` would be different (e.g. 0).

However, your compiler should warn you about what you're doing.

> warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by
>   default]

Comment: printf("%d", *p); and why this prints 2

Comment: please provide a minimum example of your code where this happens to you. For me it prints 1 as for others.

Comment: @macfij: it only prints `1` if you're on a little-endian machine (e.g. an Intel machine).  If you were on a big-endian machine (e.g. SPARC or Power), it would print `0`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you're right. By 'others' I meant people in this thread. I assume they also have intel based machines.

Answer (score 0):

When you assign a char point to the address of integer array, many things can happen, depending on the size of the integer. Below is the memory location of the array in compile under 32 bit windows OS. You may also want to cast it p=(char*)arr.

01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00

```
int arr[]={1,2,3};

// arr[0] = 1;
// arr[1] = 2;
// arr[2] = 3;

char* p;
p=(char*)arr;

// p[0] = 1
// p[1] = 0
// p[2] = 0
// p[3] = 0
// p[4] = 2
// p[5] = 0
// p[6] = 0
// p[7] = 0
// p[8] = 3
// p[9] = 0
// p[10] = 0
// p[11] = 0
```

Comment: printf("%d", *p); prints 2. why?

Comment: My compiler printed 1 on printf("%d", *p). I cannot see why it should print 2.

Comment: sorry my bad.   p = (char*)((int*)(p));printf("%d, ", *p); this prints 2

Comment: @user3465845: No it doesn't. In the context of the above code, this does not have any chance to "print 2". If you see 2, it means that you made some changes to your code and you are not showing them to us. Nobody here's telepathic.

Comment: I do not see why this code is needed p = (char*)((int*)(p));?

Comment: `p = (char*)((int*)(p))` is a no-op in this case. It does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is invalid. In C language an `int *` pointer cannot be assigned to a `char *` pointer without an explicit conversion. C language prohibits assignment of incompatible pointer types. (I.e. it prohibits implicit conversion between such types). Your compiler probably issued a diagnostic message telling you exactly the same thing. Your code contains constraint violation - it is not a valid C code.

This conversion was legal a long time ago, in archaic non-standardized versions of C language. For that reason, by default C compilers are rather permissive with regard to invalid code of this kind. They issue diagnostic messages as "warnings", but continue to compile the code, which misleads some people into believing that the code is valid.

Many C compilers offer you additional options that make them more explicit in detecting such errors. For example, in GCC you have to specify `-pedantic-errors` switch to have this constraint violation reported with an "error" message.

If your compiler accepted the code, its behavior is the same as if you wrote `p = (char *) arr`, i.e. it makes `p` point to the beginning of the `arr` array. That's all there is to it. If you attempt to access the array data through pointer `p`, you will simply *reinterpret* the memory occupied by `arr` as a sequence of `char`s. What you will see there will depend on many implementation-dependent factors. (I.e. there are no universal answers to your "Why do I see `0` there? Why do I see `2` there?" questions.) For example, the reinterpreted data will look different between *big-endian* and *little-endian* platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler should give you a warning that this is not compatible.

After assignment , lets say address of arr is 1000,  arr[0] will be at address 1000, arr[1] will be at address 1004 and arr[2] will be at address 1008

Now p points to arr, so it points to address 1000, so every time you want to access arr[1] you will have to use *(p + 4) since char is 1 byte only (Also care should be taken if its a little endian or big endian machine)

Though its incompatible you can use it but you should be carefull when you use this assignment.

**gdb output.**

```
(gdb) p *p
$8 = 1 '\001' 

(gdb) p *(p+1)
$9 = 0 '\000'

(gdb) p *(p+2)
$10 = 0 '\000'

(gdb) p *(p+3)
$11 = 0 '\000'

(gdb) p *(p+4)
$12 = 2 '\002'

(gdb) p *(p+5)
$13 = 0 '\000'

(gdb) p *(p+6)
$14 = 0 '\000'

(gdb) p *(p+7)
$15 = 0 '\000'

(gdb) p *(p+8)
$16 = 3 '\003'
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can assign a address of variable of any type to pointer of any type (however you may get a warning about assigning incompatible pointer type). This is because sizeof pointer of any type is same.

For Example:-

```
int main(void)
{
    char *c;
    int *i;
    float *f;
    printf("%d %d %d",sizeof(c),sizeof(i),sizeof(f)); //  Output: 4 4 4
}
```

**Side effect of this:**

Consider the following example:

```
int main(void)
{
     int i1=127;
     int i2=128;

     char *c1=&i1;
     char *c2=&i2; 

     printf("%d %d",*c1,*c2);  //Output : 127 -128
}
```

In order to understand this output you need to consider binary values of variables.

Lets start with i1:- Binary value of i1 is

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 01111111
```

and by assigning address of this memory to char pointer causes char pointer c1 to point to first byte (Little Endian Method) .

Now binary value of i2 is

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 10000000
```

here again c2 points to first byte but why output is -128?
because first byte is 10000000 that sign bit is 1 which means number is negative
now perform a reverse operation of 2's complement

```
10000000 ---> 01111111(minus one) --->10000000(one's complement)
```